# Optional.ofNullable doesn't seem to work if my inner objects are null?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a nested class structure that I use to deserialize my data:

```
Class A has a single property that is an object of Class B (say b)
Class B has a single property that is an object of Class C (say c)
Class C has a single property that is an object of Class D (say d)
Class D has a single property that is a a string (say e)
```

I have data that looks like

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>>> input =
                ImmutableMap.of("Key",
                        ImmutableList.of(ImmutableMap.of("a",
                                ImmutableMap.of("b",
                                        ImmutableMap.of("c",
                                                ImmutableMap.of("d", "e"))))));
```

I want to parse this multilevel map and put the result into a map

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
```

At the end, I expect `result` map to contain this at the end: `["key", "e"]`

I have this code that works if the map contain all the intermediate keys `a, b, c and d`

```
mapping.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(l -> l.getValue().stream()
                    .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                    .map(opta -> opta.map(A::getB))
                    .map(optb -> optb.map(B::getC))
                    .map(optc -> optc.map(C::getD))
                    .map(optd -> optd.map(D::getE))
                    .map(optv -> optv.orElse("default"))
                    .map(m -> result.put(l.getKey(), m))
                    .count())
            .count();
```

but for example say if  the input is

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>>> input =
                    ImmutableMap.of("Key",
                        ImmutableList.of(ImmutableMap.of("a",
                                ImmutableMap.of("b",null))));
```

then my code fails:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: b=null
```

Why is my `Optional.isNullable` not working?

Comment: Can you show the exception being thrown? Assuming that is what you mean by **not working** and **fails**.

Comment: Just edited my question and added the exception thrown

Comment: Not everything is provided so it's difficult to easily debug this. Look into SSCCE.

Comment: Sorry its getting difficult for me to create a SSCCE because its my office related code that I have edited to hide original variables and rest of the code..however I simplified my code a bit, if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ImmutableMap`, and `ImmutableMap` does not like `null` key or value: https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of-K-V-

> `public static <K,V> ImmutableMap<K,V> of(K k1, V v1)`
>
> Returns an immutable map containing a single entry. This map behaves
>   and performs comparably to `Collections.singletonMap(K, V)` but **will
>   not accept a null key or value**. It is preferable mainly for
>   consistency and maintainability of your code.

The message is produced by this method: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/82b3e9806dc3422e51ecb9400d8f50404b083dde/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/CollectPreconditions.java#L28

```
  static void checkEntryNotNull(Object key, Object value) {
    if (key == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("null key in entry: null=" + value);
    } else if (value == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("null value in entry: " + key + "=null");
    }
  }
```

On the other hand, I think you should use specialized rather than map... I'm pretty sure that such kind of type is giving headache to your team or other reader:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>>>
```

Comment: Wow! you are so right! the issue was I was testing using a null value in ImmutableMap..thanks!